# Installing Apache Cordova, unable to locate package

Tags: 14.04, package-management, python, chroot

Got Cordova installed and able to make an app. I have to run `sudo click chroot -a armhf -f ubuntu-sdk-14.10 create` to install the Ubuntu SDK, so I can later build to Ubuntu. When I run the command, I get

```
E: Unable to locate package qtsensors5-dev
Command returned 100: schroot -u root -c source:click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf -- /finish.sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 86, in 
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 82, in main
    return mod.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/commands/chroot.py", line 231, in run
    return args.func(parser, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/commands/chroot.py", line 67, in create
    return chroot.create(args.keep_broken_chroot)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/chroot.py", line 404, in create
    self.full_name, ret_code))
click.chroot.ClickChrootException: Failed to create chroot 'click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf' (exit status 100)
```

I've made sure that the qtsensors5-dev package is installed already.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure why this worked, but...
Followed the tutorial [here](http://www.himpfen.com/install-apache-cordova-ubuntu/), installed Cordova with NodeJS. Can successfully build to Ubuntu now.

> Install NodeJS:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install nodejs
> ```
>
> If that doesn’t work, try using a PPA:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install python-software-properties 
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js 
> sudo apt-get update 
> sudo apt-get install nodejs
> ```
>
> Then install NPM:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install npm
> ```
>
> Cordova uses Git in the background to download assets when creating a
>   new project, so:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install git
> ```
>
> Finally, install Apache Cordova using NPM:
>
> sudo npm install -g cordova

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to check if your installation is successful and you have Cordova installed:

```
cordova -v
```

If you get `cordova command not found` this means you don't have Cordova, use this command to install it:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

After installation use this command to check package location:

```
whereis cordova
```

it will list locations of Cordova related packages.

Comment: I have Cordova installed. Results of `whereis`:
`cordova: /usr/bin/cordova /usr/bin/X11/cordova`

Comment: That's where your archives are located, go to these locations and you will find the package you are looking for